# Bash script to start a process with a command, then obtain and store the PID of that process

Tags: process

I want to write a bash script to start a process with a command, and then obtain the PID of that started process and store it in a variable.

For example, suppose I write a bash script to launch `top`. I would like to store `top`'s process ID in a variable such as `PID`. How can I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=<value of top's process ID>
```

Comment: Does it need to be `top`, specifically? Or can it be a command that can be run in the background?

Comment: top does not like running without a tty.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example

```
top &
PID=$!
```

Comment: Have you tried this specific example?

Comment: Leaving aside the silliness of running top as a background process, this appears to be exactly what was asked. No reason given for downvoting it. Just to make sure, I ran it myself; it works here. Answer upvoted.